# How to share a file inside kube-ovn-monitor pod to another pod in a different namespace involving shared volumes

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes, persistent-storage, persistent-volume-claims

I need to share the conf.db file located in /etc/openvswitch directory inside the kubeovn pod to another pod called ipmonitor involving a shared storage such that both pods can access and any changes made in the conf.db inside the ipmonitor pod should reflect in the other pods in the kubernetes cluster.

I created pv and pvc

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: shared-storage-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  hostPath:
    path: /etc/openvswitch
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: shared-storage-pvc
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

and mounted the same pvc in both pods and kube ovn pod is running with the pvc with bound mount but the ipmonitor pod is stuck in pending state with message:

```
Volumes:
  shared-storage:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  shared-storage-pvc
    ReadOnly:   false


Warning  FailedScheduling  10m (x171 over 14h)  default-scheduler  0/1 nodes are available: persistentvolumeclaim "shared-storage-pvc" not found. preemption: 0/1 nodes are available: 1 No preemption victims found for incoming pod..
```

Comment: This shared-file setup isn't usually a best practice.  Can you change your application code to use a shared relational database or some other sort of data store, that you'd run in a separate StatefulSet?  This would avoid a wide range of problems around both programs trying to edit the shared file, especially if they can't be scheduled on the same node.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to know the supported [storageclass](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/) or [volume plugin](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#volume-mode:%7E:text=Important!%20A%20volume%20can%20only%20be%20mounted%20using%20one%20access%20mode%20at%20a%20time%2C%20even%20if%20it%20supports%20many.) being used since not all storage supports ReadWriteMany [accessModes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes). You can see the sample configuration and more on the attached links.